# Send Signalr message to specific user

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

In my project I have SignalR set up where messages are getting sent to every user that connects to my site. I'm in the process of changing this so my messages only go to those users that generated them. However, I am unable to get my users identity and I was hoping someone would be able to tell me what I've done wrong/missing.

In my `StartUp` class I have the following lines inside of `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
services.AddMvc(); 
services.AddAuthentication();
```

Then in my `Configure` I have the following lines:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapHub<UserErrorHub>("/UserErrorHub", options =>
  {
    options.Transports =
       HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
       HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
  });
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Next, my view has the following connection string set up in a `<script>` block:

```
 var url = "@Url.Content("~/UserErrorHub")";

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(url, { transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling}, options =>
        {
            options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;     
        }
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();
```

And finally I have the following classes in my hub:

```
public class UserErrorHub : Hub
{
    public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        string name;
        var user = Context.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            name = user.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            name = "anonymous";
        }
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("Message",  "hello there!" + name);
    }

    public async Task Message( string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}

public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

When I run my project, I am unable to get my Username to appear when I connect, instead all "anonymous" appearing which isn't what I want. Could someone please tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For my scenario I had to remove the singalR Endpoints and use the older depriecated way

```
        app.UseSignalR(builder =>
        {
            builder.MapHub<UserErrorHub >("/userErrorHub");
        });
```

Don't forget the Authorize attribute on the hub

```
       [Authorize]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that way is now depreciated and is being removed in future versions. All this would do is postpone the issue until that point. I do appreciate the help though

Comment: Yes it is, but thats the only way I got it to work. When I changed to use the endpoint mapping, it doesn't pass through the credentials, have you tried it?

Comment: @N0xus try the following if the above isn't right var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://example.com/myhub", options => {
        options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    })
    .Build();

Comment: unfortunatly the username still isn't coming through with the changes.

Comment: Did you set your launch settings as the following?  "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,